# Issue with Plot Visibility In HTML while it runs on R Markdown

Tags: r, plot, knitr

My rmd file shows all the outputs. However, when I knit my rmd file, the plot is not visible in my output html. There are no error or warnings.

The two files are attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the rest of the knitr file look like?  Especially any settings defined near the top?

Comment: Nothing out of ordinary, just the output and title defined. The knitr is otherwise perfect. The itemFrequencyPlot() later defined has also been replicated in html/word output. Issue with normal plot

Comment: So one stupid thing I just did is copy the entire code in notebook and not in R markdown, and surprisingly, its visible in preview. But why has the issue in R markdown? Is it because there are changes in image display resolutions between a notebook and rmd file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble picturing the distinction you're making.  But I'm glad it worked out.  In future SO questions, think about creating & pasting the code from a small, self-contained Rmd (or whatever file) that exhibits the problem.